# How do I paste commands into Command Blocks on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

People keep telling me just do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste but this does NOT WORK. Can someone give me an accurate way to do this? I am using 1.10.2 and using mac.

I keep getting notified that this is a duplicate of another copy-paste post but it's not. Why won't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste?

Comment: Cmd+C and Ctrl+V are two differwnt system commands that are on two completely separate systems.

Comment: User, are you using CTRL+V to paste or CMD+V to paste? (Since you're on mac, most windows commands are set to CMD instead of CTRL/ALT)

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to *copy* or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to *cut* your code into the clipboard and then *paste* it into your command block using <kbd>**cmd**</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts are the Windows equivalent of them.